# R/ShinyApp not showing plot_ly in browser but show only graph in viewer pane

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard

I am facing the same issue as mentioned in 
[R/Shiny plots do not show in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904212/r-shiny-plots-do-not-show-in-the-browser)

But in my case reactivePlot() is not working.It shows

> error i.e "reactivePlot is deprecated. Please use renderPlot instead."

The code doesn't throw any error. It works fine. Issue is only with displaying plotly graph in the browser. I tried it on all browser, graph is displayed on viewer pane instead of the browser, although If I plot other chart like barplot it easily get displayed on the browser. 
I am not able to resolve the issue!! Help me out!! 
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: @AaghazHussain - in fact, `renderPlotly()` (and `plotlyOutput()`), I believe

Comment: @SymbolixAU right

Comment: @SymbolixAu it solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: You should post it as a solution, not just a comment. It may help others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just an example that how it solved my problem.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
   fluidRow(
    box(plotlyOutput("plot1", height = "400px", width = "600px"))   
   )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
  plot_ly(d, x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~carat,
        size = ~carat, text = ~paste("Clarity: ", clarity))    
 })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using `plotly()` in the UI and `renderPlotly()` in the server.